# Create a command on crontab that stream editor and rewrite a file every 15 minutes

Tags: bash, sed, cron

Let's say I have a file with patterns to match into another file:

`file_names.txt`

```
pfg022G
pfg022T
pfg068T
pfg130T
pfg181G
pfg181T
pfg424G
pfg424T
```

I would like to use `file_names.txt` and use `sed` command into `example.conf`:

`example.conf`

```
{
  "ExomeGermlineSingleSample.sample_and_unmapped_bams": {
    "flowcell_unmapped_bams": ["/groups/cgsd/alexandre/gatk-workflows/src/ubam/pfg022G.unmapped.bam"],
    "unmapped_bam_suffix": ".unmapped.bam",
    "sample_name": "pfg022G",
    "base_file_name": "pfg022G.GRCh38DH.target",
    "final_gvcf_base_name": "pfg022G.GRCh38DH.target"
  },
```

The sed command would replace `pfg022G` on `example.conf` with `pfg022T`, which is the next item in `file_names.txt` (`sed s/pfg022G/pfg022T/`). The `example.conf` at this point should look like this:

```
{
  "ExomeGermlineSingleSample.sample_and_unmapped_bams": {
    "flowcell_unmapped_bams": ["/groups/cgsd/alexandre/gatk-workflows/src/ubam/pfg022T.unmapped.bam"],
    "unmapped_bam_suffix": ".unmapped.bam",
    "sample_name": "pfg022T",
    "base_file_name": "pfg022T.GRCh38DH.target",
    "final_gvcf_base_name": "pfg022T.GRCh38DH.target"
  },
```

After 15 minutes the substitution should be `pfg022T` to `pfg068T` and so on until all the items in `file_names.txt` are exhausted.

Comment: It is unclear from your question, at which point you get stuck. It seems to me that you need to implement a **state** somehow: Each execution needs to know, which name has been substituted the last time, so that it can choose the next name; but without seeing any code from your side, how you try to approach the problem, there is not much one can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following crontab would run your script every 15 minutes:

```
# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  *   command to be executed
 15  *  *  *  *   /path/to/script
```

With `script` reading

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
file1="file_names.txt"
file2="example.conf"
sed -i -e "$(awk '(NR>1){print "s/"p"/"$1"/g"}{p=$1}' $file1 | tac)" example.conf
```

The trick we use here is to do revere substitution. The file `example.conf` always contains only one string which is also in "file_names.txt". So if you attempt to substitute from the last to the front you will only do a single substitution.

We use `awk` here to build a `sed`-script and `tac` to reverse it so that we only have a single match:

```
$ awk '(NR>1){print "s/"p"/"$1"/g"}{p=$1}' $file_names.txt
s/pfg022G/pfg022T/g
s/pfg022T/pfg068T/g
s/pfg068T/pfg130T/g
s/pfg130T/pfg181G/g
s/pfg181G/pfg181T/g
s/pfg181T/pfg424G/g
s/pfg424G/pfg424T/g
```

If we do a `sed` with the above script, we will always end up with `pfg424T` (the last entry) as it will find a single match (assume we are in the third entry `pfg068T`), so sed will perform every substitution after that. However, when we reverse the order (using `tac`), `sed` will only find a single match.

Comment: what should I say man! Brilliant, you rock! It took me 15 minutes to find the trick of using `tac` =). This is really neat !

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to create a daemon/background process as opposed to a periodic cron job.

```
 while read str;
 do 
    sleep 900;
    sed -ri "s@(^\"flowcell_unmapped_bams.*gatk-workflows/src/ubam/)(.*)(\.unmapped\.bam\"\],.*$)@\1$str\3@;s/(^\"sample.name.*: \")(.*)(\",.*$)/\1$str\3/;s/(^\"base_file_name.*: \")(.*)(\.GRCh38DH.*$)/\1$str\3/" example.conf;
 done < file_names.txt &
```

Read the contents of file_names.txt line by line via a while loop, reading the line as a variable str. Sleep 900 seconds and then use this str variable in three sed commands. In all commands, enable regular expression interpretation with -r or -E and split the lines into three sections. Substitute the lines for sections 1, followed by the variable str and section 3. Add & at the end to run the process to the background.

Comment: this is amazing, I'm gonna need sometime to study this command. =)

Comment: No worries. If it helps resolve your issue, please take the time to accept it as a solution.

Comment: I have not tried yet but does this create a daemon/background process ? the `while` will operate every 15 min by the `sleep` command is that right ? until `while` reaches the last line

Comment: Yeah. Place the commands in a script and then execute it with & at the end to run it to the background

Comment: got it. I'm trying to understand you sed command, need to read more about all these special characters but meanwhile I believe you forgot to capture the `str` in the first line.

Comment: groups/cgsd/alexandre/gatk-workflows/src/ubam/pfg022G.unmapped.bam this line

Comment: Where is "groups/cgsd/alexandre/gatk-workflows/src/ubam" coming from?

Comment: first line of example.conf

Comment: OK, I've added that in now.

Comment: nice. I wonder what the `\1$str\3` does ?

Comment: In the sed commands the expressions in (..) represent sections and so we substitute the complete line for the first section represented by the first () then add the value of str then add the third section represented by the third (...) after.

Comment: oh ok very nice. I noticed the first `s@//` you use a bunch of `@` characters in `@\1$str\3@` that you did not use in the others. what is so special about `@` in this case ?

Comment: ahh i think I know sed can use any delimeter and you chose `@` in this case right ?

Comment: There are forward slashes in the string to replace i.e. gatk-workflows/src/ubam/ and so I used something different from "/" to avoid having to escape the forward slashes in "gatk-workflows/src/ubam/"

Comment: This is not stable. Any failure in the system will mess this up. If you reboot the system, you will restart from the beginning.

Comment: @RamanSailopal sorry I just noticed my real file has an extra field which needs to be interpreted, it's very similar in the end to this match `(\.GRCh38DH.*$)`and somehow its not working. I will edit the question

Comment: @kvantour I implement this in a server that never shuts down or reboot. always on!

Comment: @alex, ever heard of a power outage, upgrade, disk-crash, ...?

Comment: @kvantour very unlikely. if you have a better plan feel free to write an answer here. Plus this script will run for a day maximum.

Answer (score 1):

For the logic of how i think this would work,

1. Create a cronjob, or if your server shuts down periodically create an anacron job, to run a bash script every 15 minutes.
2. In the bash script you can use an `if` statement you can test with `grep` with each line in `filenames.txt` which line exists in example.conf, and if that line exists to go onto the next line in `filenames.txt`. If you are at the last string in `file_names.txt` then the bash script should stop running with the `exit` command
3. You would run the sed command to replace your string. I do think the `replace` command should be able to replace this.
4. If you have to reload the service to load the amended configuration and then to add this also afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I would perhaps just generate all the files in advance in a queue directory, and have the `cron` job pick up the next one on each invocation.

```sh
awk 'NR==FNR { a[++n] = $0; next }
    { file = $1 ".conf"
      for(i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        l = a[i]; sub("{{name}}", $0, l);
        print l >file }
      close file
    }' - file_names.txt <<\____
{
  "ExomeGermlineSingleSample.sample_and_unmapped_bams": {
    "flowcell_unmapped_bams": ["/groups/cgsd/alexandre/gatk-workflows/src/ubam/{{name}}.unmapped.bam"],
    "unmapped_bam_suffix": ".unmapped.bam",
    "sample_name": "{{name}}",
    "base_file_name": "{{name}}.GRCh38DH.target",
    "final_gvcf_base_name": "{{name}}.GRCh38DH.target"
  },
____
```

Running this on your sample `file_names.txt` creates the following files:

```
pfg022G.conf    pfg068T.conf    pfg181G.conf    pfg424G.conf
pfg022T.conf    pfg130T.conf    pfg181T.conf    pfg424T.conf
```

with contents like you would expect; here's `pfg0222G.conf`:

```
{
  "ExomeGermlineSingleSample.sample_and_unmapped_bams": {
    "flowcell_unmapped_bams": ["/groups/cgsd/alexandre/gatk-workflows/src/ubam/pfg022G.unmapped.bam"],
    "unmapped_bam_suffix": ".unmapped.bam",
    "sample_name": "pfg022G",
    "base_file_name": "pfg022G.GRCh38DH.target",
    "final_gvcf_base_name": "pfg022G.GRCh38DH.target"
  },
```

Now, your `cron` job just needs to move one of these to `example.conf` and process it. When the directory with the files is empty, you are done.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

for f in confdir/*.conf; do
  if [ -e "$f" ]; then
    # Safeguard against clobbering previous run
    if [ -e ./example.conf ]; then
      echo "$0: example.conf is still there -- skipping this run" >&2
      exit 63
    fi
    mv "$f" ./example.conf
    exec your_main_script_or_whatever
    # Should never fall through to here, but whatever
    break
  else
    echo "$0: directory empty -- aborting" >&2
  fi
done
```

To avoid a race condition -- if the previous `cron` job is still running, or failed for some reason, we don't want to be clobbering its input file. This requires `your_main_script_or_whatever` to remove `example.conf` when it completes.  If you don't care about this, maybe you can simply remove the safeguard condition from the above script.