# does sed ignore the 0 in substitution

Tags: bash, sed

Consider the following file:

`missing3.txt`

```
init
NKAML30
NKAML3
NKAML29
```

and `anotherfile.txt`:

```
"flowcell_unmapped_bams" ["/init.unmapped.bam"]
```

The following `sed` and `awk` expression carries a `0` to `NKAML29`, I don't understand why:

```
for i in {1..3};do sed -i -e "$(awk '(NR>1) {print "s/"p"/"$1"/g"}{p=$1}' missing3.txt | tac)" anotherfile.txt; done
```

But if I change `missing3.txt` to:

```
init
NKAML30
NKAML34
NKAML29
```

Things work as expected and I have the right substitution in every loop and I end up with `NKAML29` as the final replacement.

expected output for `anotherfile.txt` is:

`"flowcell_unmapped_bams" ["/NKAML29.unmapped.bam"]` when `missing3.txt` is like this:

```
init
NKAML30
NKAML3
NKAML29
```

Comment: Could you please post sample of expected output more clearly in your question for better understanding of question, thank you.

Comment: sure have a look now.

Comment: So you want to change `init` in anotherfile.txt which I get it, but what is the criteria of picking init value out of so many values from missing file? Could you please elaborate more on this one, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the underlying problem is that you are missing a word boundary. The `NKAML3` in `NKAML30` gets replaced with `NKAML29` and then no further replacements can take place.

How exactly to restrict `NKAML3` so it doesn't match `NKAML30` depends on your `sed` dialect. Try `s/\bNKAML3\b/NKAML29/` or perhaps `s/\<NKAML3\>/NKAML29/` ... or perhaps give up and refactor the entire script to Perl, where the former should work.

I'm further guessing your script is a weird attempt at reducing your problem to a [minimum reproducible example](/help/mcve) so perhaps it's not useful to analyze it in much depth; but running the same `sed -i` command three times on the same file seems awfully inefficient.  Perhaps the three identical `sed` invocations could be reduced to a single invocation with the same commands repeated three times as input;

```sh
awk '{ a[++n] = $0 }
    END { for(i=1; i<=3; i++) for (j=n; j>1; j--)
        print "s/\\b" a[j] "\\b/" a[j-1] "/" }' missing3.txt |
sed -i -f - another.txt
```

If your `sed` does not accept `-f -` to receive a script on standard input, probably save the output from Awk in a temporary file and then pass the file name to `sed -f`, or refactor some more to do the entire operation in Awk.  (If you have GNU Awk, it should have `-i inplace` which works similarly to `sed -i`.)

Comment: Actually it boils down to this other question I had https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65881231/create-a-command-on-crontab-that-stream-editor-and-rewrite-a-file-every-15-minut , however now I am using different patterns and the answer is not working anymore. I will have a look at your code in detail now. thanks

Comment: Perhaps then it would make more sense to generate a bunch of `.conf` files in advance and have your `cron` job pick up the next one by time stamp.

Answer (score 1):

sed happend 3 times, and the instruction you give it is:

```
s/NKAML3/NKAML29/g
s/NKAML30/NKAML3/g
s/init/NKAML30/g
```

First round, `init` is replaced by `NKAML30`, the result is `"flowcell_unmapped_bams" ["/NKAML30.unmapped.bam"]`

Second round, `NKAML3` is replaced by `NKAML29` (because the fist instruction matches first), result is `"flowcell_unmapped_bams" ["/NKAML290.unmapped.bam"]`

Last round, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

The output from the `awk | tac` portion of the script is:

```
s/NKAML3/NKAML29/g
s/NKAML30/NKAML3/g
s/init/NKAML30/g
```

When that is treated as a `sed` script and applied to:

```
"flowcell_unmapped_bams" ["/init.unmapped.bam"]
```

the only match is `init` which is mapped to `NKAML30` — as you observe.

If you didn't apply `tac`, you'd get different results.  Then you get `NKAML29` in the output.